# How to merge code that was merely copied (not branched) from a distant past commit?

Tags: git

A remote member of our team has been slowly making changes to code over the past two months (approximately). However, instead of making their changes within a tracked branch, they simply copied the directory's contents and made local changes and additions.

They're being asked to commit and merge their changes, so I was trying to help them with this process. However, I'm a little stumped because simply creating a new branch on `local/master`, copying and overwriting files, then performing a pull from `remote/master` did not trigger expected merge conflicts. I've also tried local merges to no avail. Basically, the status reports that all files are up-to-date and no conflicts exist.

Simply put, is there a quick method/command for getting their files merged in? I understand there's going to be some level of manual fixes involved. Does it make sense to simply checkout the first commit, branch, then merge?

Comment: It makes sense to checkout the original commit from which the code was copied from, commit the changes on top of that as a new branch, then merge this into master. If you create a new branch on top of master and copy/overwrite the working folder with the changed files from that old commit, you will essentially remove all changes done on master since that old commit. This is not what you want.

Comment: Yes, thank you @Lasse, this was my understanding. I figured that the reason it was reporting that there were no conflicts/changes was it was seeing those copied files as essentially new files/revisions from HEAD. I appreciate your comment.

Comment: Also, schedule some time with your remote member to get them on board with git :)